# VBA UserForm - Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, userform

I get

> Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

on the first Cells Value line `( .Cells(last, 1).Value = Val(TextBox1) )` when I want to run my Userform.

The Userform is triggered with a button located on another sheet and the data typed in the userform shall be delivered to the first empty row on my worksheet "MBE_Statistik". Because my data on this sheet is formatted as a table I first want to activate autofill and expand for tables (as the archive will be opened on different computers with probably different settings).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim last As Long

With Application.AutoCorrect
.AutoExpandListRange = True
.AutoFillFormulasInLists = True

End With

last = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MBE_Statistik").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MBE_Statistik")

'KW
.Cells(last, 1).Value = Val(TextBox1)

'Center Code
.Cells(last, 3).Value = Val(TextBox2)

'Ort
.Cells(last, 4).Value = Val(TextBox3)

'Projekt
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then .Cells(last, 5).Value = "Neustarter"
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then .Cells(last, 5).Value = "ISB"
If OptionButton3.Value = True Then .Cells(last, 5).Value = "Leadgenerierung"
If OptionButton4.Value = True Then .Cells(last, 5).Value = "Center Flights"

'Flight-Nr
.Cells(last, 6).Value = Val(TextBox5)

'Ansprechpartner
.Cells(last, 7).Value = Val(TextBox4)

'Agent
.Cells(last, 10).Value = Val(TextBox6)

'Ist-Stunden
.Cells(last, 8).Value = Val(TextBox13)

'Ist-Stunden
.Cells(last, 9).Value = Val(TextBox7)

'Wählversuche
.Cells(last, 11).Value = Val(TextBox8)

'Erreicht AP/Entscheider
.Cells(last, 12).Value = Val(TextBox9)

'Kein Interesse
.Cells(last, 13).Value = Val(TextBox16)

.
.
.

End With

End Sub
```

There are some more textboxes which I left out at the moment as the error is highlighted on the first.

Can somebody help me find the problem?

Comment: Write `MsgBox last & " " & TextBox1` before the error and share what you get.

Comment: I got  93  23  as a message (with 23 being the value I typed in the UserForm)

Comment: And when you press F8 twice after clicking ok on the msgbox, what happens?

Comment: The weird thing is when I continue to run the macro after the error message (in the debug mode), it runs it as wished. All the values from my textboxes are paste in the new sheet and the table is expanded for the corresponding row.

Comment: A shot in the dark... Before the line `.Cells(last, 1).Value = Val(TextBox1)` type `DoEvents` and try again?

Comment: BTW you code runs just fine for me

Comment: Maybe you turn off EVents and Recalculation beforehand.

Comment: somehow still does not work. It is crazy. Actually it also worked for me yesterday. Today when I continued working I turned off Workbook calcualtions because I hade problem with the saving process of the workbook file. I then calculated the workbook manually for one or two times after turning it on automatically again

Comment: I also tried all the ideas above. Still no chance...

Comment: Close and restart your computer? :P